# Wix add launch condition

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to add a launch condition to wix to check and see if HTTP activation is enabled on the system. I have created a managed Custom action that will return `ActionResult.Failure` or `ActionResult.Success` based on if it is enabled or not.

My thought is to then set the `InstallExecuteSequence` to call the custom action before the `LaunchConditions` action and to have a Product Condition based on this.

Does anyone know if this will work? Or if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that your custom action should set a certain property in case HTTP activation is enabled. And launch condition will check if that property is defined and based on that either let the installation go further, or terminate.

I mean there's no need to fail your CA returning ActionResult.Failure. Just set the property and let the LaunchConditions do its job.

Comment: Agreed. While a failing action will satisfies the implied requirement (conditionally abort the installer) it does not do so in a way that gives the person installing it any clue how to fix it. Much better to set the property and condition off that in a launch condition or type 19 "error" CA that includes a message.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by HTTP activation you mean Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation.  With that said...

Instead of a custom action couldn't use use a registry entry to set the property as described by Yan?  For example for IIS6 Metabase compatibility I use:

```
<Property Id="IIS_METABASE_COMPAT">
    <RegistrySearch Id="CheckIisMetabase"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components"
                    Name="Metabase"
                    Type="raw"
                    Win64="no" />
</Property>
```

And for the launch condition (the above is one of several properties in the launch condition):

```
<Condition Message="IIS6 or IIS 7 is required.  If you are running IIS7 the IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility Feature must be installed.">
    <![CDATA[IISMAJORVERSION="#6" OR (IISMAJORVERSION="#7" AND (IIS_METABASE_COMPAT OR IIS_METABASE_COMPAT_X64))]]>
</Condition>
```

I found a key at:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Communication Foundation\HTTPActivation` that might or might not be useful for this purpose.  There is also a REG_DWORD called InstallSuccess at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup\Windows Communication Foundation` that might be useful.

I can't find documentation on either of these, but I've installed both and my value for the InstallSuccess REG_DWORD is (1) and I have the key HTTPActivation present.